# Can JavaScript's function having an array.forEach return a value to the caller?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

For example:

```
  function findIndexOfFirstNonNegative(array) {
    array.forEach( (a, i) => { if (a >= 0) { return i; }});
    return null;
  }
```

it turns out the `return i;` will not return to the caller of the function `findIndexOfFirstNonNegative()`, but it will return from the fat arrow function and let the `forEach` go on (or even if it is a plain old function instead of fat arrow function, it is the same).

Is there a way to break out and return to the caller?

Comment: [how to stop Javascript forEach?](//stackoverflow.com/q/6260756), [How to short circuit Array.forEach like calling break?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2641347)

Comment: You using the wrong method if you wish to find an index of an item.  `findIndex` may be better. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods) for full list.

Comment: You may want to use Array.some for more general purposes. https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/some

Comment: @Cobaltway `Array.some` will just return true or false

Comment: @Weedoze You can use it to break the loop by returning true.

Comment: The term "fat arrow function" is obsolete. The correct term is "arrow function".

Comment: @torazaburo is it obsolete since when... since 2 weeks ago? (just kidding)

Comment: At least since the spec was published two years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex?v=example) in Javascript instead

```
array.findIndex( a => a >= 0);
```

```js
console.log([-5,-10, 0, 4].findIndex( a => a >= 0))
```

Comment: looks so beautiful...

Comment: Glad to know :) Let accept it if it's the answer you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

Use a classical loop. This will return to the function when the condition is met.

I added a `console.log()` inside the loop to show that it will stop after founding the non negative number

```js
function findIndexOfFirstNonNegative(array) {
  for (let i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++) {
    console.log("Loop item : " + array[i] + " at index " + i);
    if (array[i] >= 0) return i;
  }
  return -1;
}

console.log("Index found : " + findIndexOfFirstNonNegative([-5, 2, 1]))
```

OR

You can directly use [`Array#findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex?v=example)

```js
function findIndexOfFirstNonNegative(array) {
  return array.findIndex(a=>a>=0);
}

console.log("Index found : " + findIndexOfFirstNonNegative([-5, 2, 1]))
```

Comment: Too bad the test is not for less-than-or-equal to zero, because then we could write `a=>a<=0`.

Comment: @torazaburo Or event better `a=>a<=a` but that would be useless